# HttpClient response ReadAsAsync() doesn't fully deserialize object

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to consume a web service with the Web API client library.  My problem is that the ReadAsAsync doesn't seem to want to fully deserailize the returned object when the submitting function uses a POST method.

If I get the response as a string and manually deserailize it works.  (I get a apmsgMessage with all the fields populated)

```cs
HttpClient client = GetClient();
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/robot/Preview", ad).Result;
var msg = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<apmsgMessage>(msg.Result);
```

I originally tried the code below which returns an apmsgMessage Object, but all the fields are null.

```cs
HttpClient client = GetClient();
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/robot/Preview", ad).Result;
var msg = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<apmsgMessage>().Result;
return msg;
```

My question is why dosn't my orginal (the PostAsJsonAsync) return a apmsgMessage fully populated.  Am I doing somethign wrong with the ReadAsAsync?

Comment: Could you share the wire format of the json that is returned and also the type 'apmsgMessage'?

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same issue, and in my case I solved it by removing the `[Serializable]` attribute from the class.

I don't know why this attribute conflicts with the deserialization process, but as soon as I took that out, the `ReadAsAsync` method worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks, saved my day! Question author should mark this answer as a solution.

Comment: Gaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.  This seems the exact opposite of what it should be.  3 hours on this.  Thanks for this answer.  #whatInTheWorld