# HttpClient.ReadAsAsync<T> Returns Empty Object When Using [Serializable]

Tags: .net, json, serialization, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working with the Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Client Libraries (version 4.0.30506 since I have to run on .NET Framework 4.0) to interface with a .NET web API.  I have confirmed that the data is being received fine.  However, the object returned from the ReadAsAsync call is unpopulated (not null).  After digging around online, I found this SO post (see the answer as well):

[HttpClient response ReadAsAsync() doesn't fully deserialize object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034437/httpclient-response-readasasync-doesnt-fully-deserialize-object)

Turns out, the objects that I'm sending to the client via JSON are marked [Serializable] and that removing this attribute makes everything work fine (which I've confirmed via testing).  However, these objects need the [Serializable] attribute for other scenarios where they're used in other apps, so simply removing the attribute isn't really an option.

My code is shown below.  Calls (not shown) to the Get method return an unpopulated Customer object when the [Serializable] attribute is applied to the Customer object (as shown).  When the attribute is removed, the Customer object returned is property populated.

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class WebAPIClient
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public WebAPIClient(Uri baseAddress)
        {
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = baseAddress:
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }

        public Customer Get(int id)
        {
            string url = [code that builds url] + id.ToString();
            HttpResponseMessage response = _httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Customer>().Result;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain why I'm seeing this behavior and how I can get around it without removing the [Serializable] attribute from my data classes?

Comment: Where is your json? What is `TEntity`? How about posting a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: Additional coded added for context and clarity.

Comment: I found the solution [here][1] and have confirmed that it works.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914080/make-json-net-and-serializable-attribute-work-together

Comment: thanks it works now... a simple attribute can break so many things hahha...

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to **not** use the old "serializable" pattern at all.
Both Newtonsoft and the modern System.Text.Json serializers will serialize in a sensible way without **any** attributes.

`[JsonObject]` from the other answer is also not necessary. In this case all it's really doing is turning on a switch that `[Serializable]` turned off.

`[Serializable]` (and associated `ISerializable` interface) where some of the original ways to define how an object should be treated by things like `DataContractSerializer`. These are best left in the past :)

It is only being recognized in order to provide some backward compatibility so it behaves approximately the same as the original serializers.

There are plenty of attrs and other hooks to allow for customization. Research into the those provided directly by Newtonsoft or S.T.Json (depending on which you have configured, probably newtonsoft considering framework version you mention).

I would suggest that your future self will thank you for leaving these as pure POCOs (ie completely unattributed, bags of properties).

Answer (score 0):

In the .NET Framework 4.0, ReadAsAsync management must first perform an intermediate serialization using the 'DataContractJsonSerializer' class, rather than converting the JSON content directly to an object. This intermediate serialization operation can affect objects with attributes and prevent objects from being fully populated.

DataContractJsonSerializer manages data serialization/deserialization operations in the .NET Framework using the [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes instead of the [Serializable] attribute. Therefore, when the [Serializable] attribute is removed, the ReadAsAsync method can correctly populate the object because the intermediate serialization process is skipped.

However, you mentioned that there are situations that require the [Serializable] attribute in other scenarios. In this case, you may need to mark the Customer class using the [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes. Thus, the ReadAsAsync method uses these attributes to perform correct serialization and deserialization.

```
[Serializable]
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class SerializableCustomer
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class WebAPIClient
{
    public SerializableCustomer Get(int id)
    {
        string url = [code that builds url] + id.ToString();
        HttpResponseMessage response = _httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var customer = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Customer>().Result;
        return new SerializableCustomer { Name = customer.Name };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- I don't recommend using the [Serializable] attribute inside your model because you will break the Single Responsibility Principle clause in the SOLID rules.
- Single Responsibility Principle (SRP): The [Serializable] attribute combines the object's responsibilities for data storage and data communication. This is contrary to SRP, because the primary responsibility of a class should be separate.
- You can use the 'JsonConvert' class to specifically serialize and deserialize JSON data using the Newtonsoft.Json library. This way you can properly handle objects with JSON by addressing the issues created by the [Serializable] attribute.

  ```
   public async Task<Customer> GetAsync(int id){
   string url = [url oluşturan kod] + id.ToString();
   HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
   response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

   string jsonContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(jsonContent);}
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this ...

```
public static class ApiUtil
{
    static HttpClient GetApiClient()
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiUrl"]);
                return client;
            }

    public static async Task<Customer> GetCustomer(int id)
            {
                var client = GetApiClient();
                string query = "Customers(" + id + ")";
                var response = await client.GetAsync(query);
                return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Customer>();
            }
}
```

then to use this you might do something like this in an async method ...

```
var customer = await ApiUtil.GetCustomer(1);
```

if you cant use async and await when calling this try something like ...

```
var customerTask = ApiUtil.GetCustomer(1);
customerTask.Wait();
var customer = customerTask.Result;
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, which is that a class marked [Serializable] doesn't get deserialized by ReadAsAsync<T>. The await is irrelevant.

Comment: I completely agree the await is just how I choose to use tasks, I can assure you the code sample above is working fine for me on types I have marked as serializable. This code was copied from my code base (currently working in production environment) so I'm dam sure it works on the types I have ... maybe the problem isn't the serializable attrib?

Comment: Thought I'd respond to this... it isn't that the code doesn't work, rather that it wasn't a good answer. OP found the answer on a slightly different question (adding [JsonObject]), I wish they'd added it as an answer here.

Comment: Could you link me to the solution? Just curious ... think I probably missed something.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me, and the OP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20914389 . It looks like it was caused by a change in json.net. To be clear again, I don't think there's anything wrong with your code per se, it just doesn't fit this question.